# Celery beat not starting on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have an app that I've launched on Heroku, but the Celery beat process doesn't start when I start the server.

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn -w 4 connect.wsgi
celery: python manage.py celeryd -c 3 --beat
```

The worker can be seen to be started after the Heroku app is launched:

```
$ heroku ps

=== web (Free): gunicorn -w 4 connect.wsgi (1)
web.1: starting 2016/07/13 16:17:18 -0400 (~ 9s ago)

=== celery (Free): python manage.py celeryd -c 3 --beat (1)
celery.1: up 2016/07/13 16:17:25 -0400 (~ 2s ago)
```

However, in order to get the Celery beat process running, I have to explicitly start it in Heroku with:

```
heroku run python manage.py celerybeat
```

Celery beat launches fine locally. Is this a limitation of Heroku or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku only allow two free Dyno instances in one application if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: That's too bad... It's weird that you can start a process in the terminal to get a third going.

Answer (score 7):

If your running on a free tier heroku with a single dyno then you best bet is to use honcho python clone of foreman a tool for managing Procfile-based applications. clone https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho, This will allow you to fork mutiple processes for your celery beat/workers. You will still be limited by heroku's free tier memory 512MB ram and dyno operating hours. So nothing too heavy good for quick dev and poc's

install honcho

> pip install honcho

Ensure honcho is part of your requirement.txt

> pip freeze > requirements.txt

Create a ProcfileHoncho store all your original Procfile content

**ProcfileHoncho**

```
web: gunicorn myDjangoApp.wsgi --log-file -
worker1: celery -A myDjangoApp beat -l info
worker2: celery -A myDjangoApp worker -l info
```

**Procfile**

```
web: honcho start -f ProcfileHoncho
```

ensure you load up your broker url via config vars and point to your free managed broker. Am sure you can find one free broker with a quick google search

```
git push heroku master
heroku logs -t
```

Check out the logs see if they are any errors. At this point you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

@Jared Goguen: Hi pal,

You probable need to scale up your workers in Heroku,

> Deploying on Heroku
>
> If you already created a Procfile above and attached the appropriate add-ons for the message broker and result store, all that’s left to do is push and scale your app:

```
git push heroku master

heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

> Of course, at any time you can scale to any number of worker dynos. Now run a task just like you did locally:

```
heroku run python

>>> import tasks
>>> tasks.add.delay(1, 2)
```

> You should see the task running in the application logs:

```
heroku logs -t -p worker
```

Source: [Heroku Guides](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku)

Comment: PS: I'm sorry about the poor format, SO gave me errors with quoted code.

Comment: Tried this before and ran into the "not enough dynos" issue, oh well.

Comment: As @Muhlen said in the other answer, you need to upgrade your account, of course you can start it from terminal, but the same dyno will be attending it (_not recommended_)